# Download File From Server on Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, download

I've used this Gist (not mine) to download a CSV file from the server.
It works great in Chrome, Edge and Safari.

https://gist.github.com/handleman/6ac609c084c735e6738f5d155e29a874

In IE it opens into a new tab, and in FireFox it prompts to download, but without an file extension.

In particular, I'd like to be able to add an extension to Firefox.  Is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the checks for IE and Firefox.

Updated version:

```js
function downloadFile(sUrl) {
  //iOS devices do not support downloading. We have to inform user about this.
  if (/(iP)/g.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // alert('Your device does not support files downloading. Please try again in desktop browser.');
    window.open(sUrl, '_blank');
    return false;
  }

  //Creating new link node.
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = sUrl;
  link.setAttribute('target','_blank');

  if (link.download !== undefined) {
    //Set HTML5 download attribute. This will prevent file from opening if supported.
    var fileName = sUrl.substring(sUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, sUrl.length);
    link.download = fileName;
  }

  //Dispatching click event.
  if (document.createEvent) {
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e.initEvent('click', true, true);
    link.dispatchEvent(e);
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey!  This worked, at least for Firefox!  It changes the name to the correct file name too.  IE11 still opens into a new tab, but I think that is something we can live with.

Comment: Good to hear :) I'm glad I could help.